Configuration of Daily Azure Cost export schedule
I have scheduled month-to-date Azure Cost export and it's perfectly running everyday and built a structure on top of this exports and visualizing the cost for my teams.
However, data export run is taking place at 4:30 PM UTC everyday and due to this reason, I have 2 days gap in my reports.
I checked

the details of the scheduled export and there is no configuration for time of export.

manualy trigger export in 06:30AM UTC and after successful run, "estimated next run" changed to next day 06:30 AM UTC. However, after the next day, export time again changed back to 04:30PM UTC.

I created a new export at 06:30AM UTC and run export,"estimated next run" changed to next day 06:30 AM UTC. However, again, after the next day, export time again changed back to 04:30PM UTC.


Is there any way to solve this and run this export before 06:30AM UTC everyday? Or should I create a trigger via ADF/Synapse/Logic App to trigger export mornings?

Bear çağatay yılmaz, the reply is no.
There is no way to have a grip on that. Is Microsoft that manages at what time that export takes place.
The Month-to-Date export should be called Month-to-2-days-ago export.

Thanks Mink francesco mantovani :)
Unofrtunately yes, still trying to survive with 2 days gap.

Tell to your manager that there is no solution. That's it. @çağatayyılmaz

And if you try to pull that gap of 2 days with Azure REST API you will create an even greater mess: the last 2 days keeps recalculating so you could pull in FALSE DATA! Tell to you manager to relax.
